# Avoiding data loss with a SQL Server script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, migration

I work for a customer who has his own database management team and I need to deploy my new web application version within a SQL Server 2008 script (I am not in position to execute any actions on their systems). I can't back up myself their database and I'm not sure they'll do it so if I delete all data it's gonna be terrible.

Therefore, I'm looking for a solution to back-up if possible the database, extract the existing datas, execute the new statements of my script, and re-include the datas saved in the database.
It is possible to do this in a SQL server script ?

More generally, how can I safely update schemas and datas of a SQL Server database within a script without losing all data inside ?

PS :

Currently, I'm using in the dev environment the initial database schema and the newest. So, I use Visual Studio 2012 with Data Tools to make Schema comparison and generate the update script.

Answer (score 0):

You start with a copy of the database schema with sample data against which you can develop and test.

Then you write scripts (perhaps with the aid of a tool like [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)) that updates the schema to be compatible with the new version of your application, retaining the data in the database.

You deliver these tested schema modification scripts along with the new version of your application for the customer's administrators to test and apply to the target database as part of the application upgrade.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do currently but I fear the risk to corrupt the existing data with the new schemas (I have no second chance). So I'm looking for a SQL script which I can insert to export data or back-up the database, or something.

Comment: They (or you) should definitely take database backups before the upgrade to enable a rollback in case of trouble.

Comment: Ok so it's not possible to do this with a script. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can backup a database with a script, sure.